# Onclick download the highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Based on the selected options and on-click link, chart will be generated. For that we used highcharts. But the requirement is user should be able to download the chart from the on-click link.

Now user, select the option and from on-click user generate the chart and then from charts user have options to download the chart.

Currently, we have this : [image]

This chart will open onClick, but client requirment is instead of opening the chart user should be able to download the chart.

Comment: Is the chart made of SVG or canvas or an image??

Comment: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click  ?

Comment: If you want to "instead of opening the chart" download it, you must first draw the element or the exporting wont work, unless you cache the images somewhere on the server and request it this way. I'm not sure if you can hide the element (probably can) and grab it from there. [Here's different ways to export the chart](https://gist.github.com/philfreo/0a4d899de4257e08a000).

Comment: @Adriani6 Thanks let me do research on it

Comment: @Adriani6 any idea on this:-    // Method 1: simply use Highcharts built-in functionality (SVG -> Highcharts server -> PNG)

highcharts.exportChart({
    filename: filename
});

Comment: @sah I have provided a full answer below. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can not just download a chart without first rendering it or caching the image of the rendered chart and storing it on the server.

Your solution that I came up with is a combination of CSS and Highcharts API.

You can use the `exportChart` functionality that is built-in into HighCharts library and define the format you want the image in. 
Possible values are `image/png`, `image/jpeg`, `application/pdf` and `image/svg+xml`.

The trick is to hide the chart somewhere on the page by setting `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` on the actual chart. This way users will not see the chart, but you will actually generate one and use it to get the image of it.

JS Sample:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }]

});

function downloadJPG(){
    chart.exportChart({type:"image/jpeg"});
}

function downloadPNG(){
    chart.exportChart({type:"image/png"});
}
```

[Full Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfqq38c7/1/)

Comment: Thanks for understanding my issue and solution

Comment: @sah Happy to help.

Comment: this works for static chart. My chart is dynamic its not printing dynamic file.

Comment: @Adriani6 There are multiple charts on my page and I want to download them all. When running multiple exports as follows - chart1.exportChart({filename:'chart1',type:"application/pdf"}); chart2.exportChart({filename:'chart2',type:"application/pdf"}); only second one is getting downloaded. Please help.